# Converting a value to corresponding text

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I am trying to get my script finished for checking powershell versions on remote machines, and I am now down to one last part, I am getting a version number of the file back from powershell but I am looking for a way to turn 6.2.1200.XXX to Version 3, my script thus far is

```
Foreach ($Computer in $Computers)
{
    Try
    {
        Write-Host "Checking Computer $Computer"
        $path = "\\$Computer\C$\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
        if (test-path $path)
        {
            Write-host "Powershell is installed::"
            [bool](ls $path).VersionInfo
            Write-host " "
            Write-host "Powershell Remoting Enabled::"
            [bool](Test-WSMan -ComputerName $Computer -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Host "Powershell isn't installed" -ForegroundColor 'Red'
        }
        Write-Host "Finished Checking Computer $Computer"
    }
```

Comment: Please don't try to reverse lookup based on Windows version.  This can break in so many dumb ways, such as the user installing PS5 on Win7, a SP bringing new features to old OS, or simply a new OS coming out with a number scheme you haven't seen.  Just ask PowerShell what version it's running.  `Powershell.exe -C "$PSVersionTable.PSVersion"`

Comment: @RyanBemrose your way would work if I could remote powershell to every machine which I can't and it is not checking the version of windows but the version of the powershell file, which is set by the vendor(Microsoft)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file versions which include the revision, might change as updates get installed, but the first 3 numbers should be useful. You can cast as a `[version]` or you can just use a simple split or replace to get rid of the build.

You could then make a hashtable with version numbers as keys and PS versions as values.

```powershell
$fileVer = [version](Get-Item $path).VersionInfo
$myVer = "{0}.{1}.{2}" -f $fileVer.Major,$fileVer.Minor,$fileVer.Build

$verTable = @{
    '6.3.1200' = 3
    '6.3.9600' = 4
}

$psVer = $verTable[$myVer]
```

Otherwise, if you've determined that PowerShell remoting is in fact enabled, another way would be to just ask it:

```powershell
$prEnabled = [bool](Test-WSMan -ComputerName $Computer -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
if ($prEnabled) {
    $psVer = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock { $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major }
}
```

#### Alternatives for setting `$myVer`:

String substitution:

```powershell
$fileVer = [version](Get-Item $path).VersionInfo
$myVer = "$($fileVer.Major).$($fileVer.Minor).$($fileVer.Build)"
```

Replace (regular expression):

```powershell
$fileVer = (Get-Item $path).VersionInfo
$myVer = $fileVer -replace '\.\d+$',''
# replaces the last dot and any digits with nothing
```

Split with range:

```powershell
$fileVer = (Get-Item $path).VersionInfo
$myVer = ($fileVer -split '\.')[0..2]
# splits on a literal dot, then uses a range to get the first 3 elements of the array
```

Using `switch -wildcard` (credit to Ansgar Wiechers):

```powershell
$fileVer = (Get-Item $path).VersionInfo.ProductVersion
$myVer = switch -Wildcard ($fileVer) {
    '6.3.1200.*' { 3 }
    '6.3.9600.*' { 4 }
}
```

Comment: Another option would be to use a `switch -wildcard` statement on the `.VersionInfo.ProductVersion` property.

Comment: @briantist I added in the hash table and got it coded in but now my script stops at that point and goes no further.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers edited it into the answer. I *always* forget about `switch -Wildcard`, thanks!

Comment: @Luke do you mean it errors out? Edit the new code into the question, and if there's an error, show that too.

Comment: it was the `[version]` part of the statement and it was a logic error, but the switch works great.

Comment: @briantist I added the final code as an answer, but when I took out `[version]` it finished just never told me the version. but while it was in there it just stopped at that spot.

Answer (score 0):

The code I ended with is

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    $ComputerName
)
if (Test-Path $ComputerName)
{
    $Computers = Get-Content $ComputerName
}
Else
{
    $Computers = $ComputerName
}

Foreach ($Computer in $Computers)
{
    Try
    {
        Write-Host "Checking Computer $Computer"
        $path = "\\$Computer\C$\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
        $fileVer = (Get-Item $path).VersionInfo.ProductVersion
        $myVer = switch -Wildcard ($fileVer)
        {
            '6.0.6002.*' { 1 }
            '6.1.7600.*' { 2 }
            '6.2.9200.*' { 3 }
            '6.3.9600.*' { 4 }
        }

        if (test-path $path)
        {
            Write-host "Powershell is installed::"
            [bool](ls $path).VersionInfo
            Write-host " "
            Write-host "Powershell Version installed::"
            Write-host " $myVer "
            Write-host " "
            Write-host "Powershell Remoting Enabled::"
            [bool](Test-WSMan -ComputerName $Computer -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Host "Powershell isn't installed" -ForegroundColor 'Red'
        }
        Write-Host "Finished Checking Computer $Computer"
    }

    catch { }
}
```

Comment: The `$myVer` variable contains the version. If you want to display it you would use something like `Write-Host $myVer`.